# Javascript knocks out CSS:hover?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, rollover

Hi im trying to make the Product Categories menu work on this page:

http://www.jaybrand.co.uk/p1.html

at the moment the page loads and CSS hover works to set the background position so that the graphic behind makes a roll over effect.

i put some javascript to set the background position to the roll over on click, but this knocks out the CSS hover:

onclick="setStyle('c1','backgroundPosition','0px 0px');

it means that c1:hover no longer works.. i tried putting   !important  in the CSS c1:hover background position and this fixed it in Firefox but not IE.

How can i write something in Javascript to also say:

onclick="setStyle('c1:hover','backgroundPosition','-276px 0px');

......... i know Javascript does not do hyphens and the way to get for example "background-position" in CSS is to ditch the hyphen and make "P"osition capitol. perhaps something can be done also to get to the CSS hover attribute?

Answer (score 1):

When you set an element's `style.backgroundPosition`, it's the same as setting an inline `style="background-position: ..."` attribute. Since inline style attributes override stylesheet rules, the hover/non-hover rules can never again affect the background position.

You could *remove* the `backgroundPosition` rule for elements being unselected so that the stylesheet rules can shine through. But really, your code needs a serious refactoring: manually setting every background position in the `onclick` is ugly and unmaintainable.

Instead, switch a class around to flag the selected link, eg. styled like this:

```
.c { background: url(...); }
#c1.selected, #c1:hover { background-position: -276px 0; }
#c2.selected, #c2:hover { background-position: -276px -61px; }
...
```

markup:

```
<h2><a class="c selected" id="c1" href="#productcats">Products</a></h2>
<a class="c" id="c2" href="#rice">Rice</a>
...
```

(`a`-inside-`h2` because the other way around is invalid.)

script:

```
var selected= $('#c1');
$('.c').click(function() {
    // Move the 'selected' class to the new element
    //
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected= $(this);
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    // Scroll target element into view
    //
    var y= $(this.hash).offset().top-$('#slide').offset().top;
    $('#slide').animate({top: -y+'px'}, {duration: 450, queue: false});

    return false;
});
```

Note this uses the href of the links to point to where they go, which will improve accessibility on non-visual browsers. You should also add some code to look at the `location.hash` on page load and if you see something there, scroll that page into view. Otherwise, it will be impossible to bookmark one of your subpages, or to middle-click-new-tab the links or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar the other day, not 100% sure but this might help push you in the right direction..

```
 onclick="document.getElementById('c1:hover').style.cssText='backgroundPosition: -276px 0px;';"
```